# Java Multi-threading: make a thread to start after checking the returned value from the first thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that basically makes a connection to the server and if the connection is successful, it will return a positive ID number. I would like to create another thread that will check if the current ID number is positive and runs once it detects the ID is positive.

```
// My first thread that establishes connection 

new Thread() {
    public void run(){
          makeConnection();
          // this makeConnection method will make the ID become a positive number if the connection is fully established.
    }
}.start();
```

Note that `obj.getCurrentId()` returns the current ID number. But I am struggling to write the second thread and how it communicates with the first thread. Can someone kindly help me out please? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to use the connection only after creating the connection is successful. Why not use one thread to do both? Threads are for concurrent tasks.

Comment: Because it takes time to actually connect to the server and for it to make the ID become positive. If I put both tasks under the same thread , I am afraid that the "check whether the ID is positive" code may be executed when the full connection has not been fully established yet.

Comment: So why would having two thread solve this problem. If you use one thread you at least know you can't use the connection until the makeConnection() has returned.

Comment: You are describing sequential execution. There is no reason for using two separate threads for this. 'I am afraid that the "check whether the ID is positive" code may be executed when the full connection has not been fully established yet' doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use `Java 8` a good way to implement it is with [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) as it will allow you to define a flow of asynchronous tasks to execute.

So for example here the main code could be:

```
// Call connect asynchronously using the common pool from a given thread
// then execute someMethod using another thread
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(MyClass::connect)
    .thenCompose(MyClass::someMethodAsync);
```

The method `connect` of the class `MyClass` could be:

```
public static int connect() {
    try {
        SomeClass obj = makeConnection();
        // ok so we return a positive value
        return obj.getCurrentId();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do something here
    }
    // ko so we return a negative value
    return -1;
}
```

The method `someMethodAsync` of the class `MyClass` could be:

```
public static CompletionStage<Void> someMethodAsync(int id) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> MyClass.someMethod(id));
}
```

The method `someMethod` of the class `MyClass` could be:

```
public static Void someMethod(int id) {
    if (id > 0) {
        // do something
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Another approach could be to rely on `wait`/`notify`/`notifyAll` or `await`/`signal`/`signalAll` to notify the other thread that the `id` has changed.

So your code could be something like that:

```
public class SomeClass {
    /**
     * The current id
     */
    private int currentId;
    /**
     * The object's monitor
     */
    private final Object monitor = new Object();

    /**
     * @return the current id
     */
    public int getCurrentId() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            return this.currentId;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current id and notifies waiting threads
     */
    public void setCurrentId(final int currentId) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            this.currentId = currentId;
            monitor.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes the calling thread wait until the id is positive
     * @throws InterruptedException if current thread is interrupted while waiting
     */
    public void waitForPositiveId() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            while (currentId <= 0) {
                monitor.wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So your first thread will simply call `makeConnection()` assuming that internally it calls the setter `setCurrentId` of `SomeClass` and the second thread will start by calling `waitForPositiveId()` to make it wait until the id is positive.

**NB:** This approach will make the second thread wait for ever if `makeConnection()` fails.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `ExecutorService` with `Callable` interface - just return your ID number in `Future` result.

Have a look at [ExecutorService.html#submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-)

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

1. Create an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-)
2. Submit the first task : `ConnectionTask` and get the result
3. Submit the second task:  `ValidationTask` and get the result
4. Depending on the result you can take next set of actions.

Sample code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CallablePollingDemo{
    public CallablePollingDemo(){
        System.out.println("creating service");
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);      
        try{
            Future future1 = service.submit(new ConnectionTask());  
            int result1 = ((Integer)future1.get()).intValue();
            System.out.println("Result from ConnectionTask task:"+result1);
            if ( result1 > 0){ // change this condition to suit your requirement
                Future future2 = service.submit(new ValidationTask(result1));  
                int result2 = ((Integer)future2.get()).intValue();
                System.out.println("Result from ValidationTask task:"+result2);
            }

        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        service.shutdown();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        CallablePollingDemo demo = new CallablePollingDemo();
    }
    class ConnectionTask implements Callable<Integer>{

        public ConnectionTask(){

        }
        public Integer call(){
            int id = 1;
            // Add your business logic here , make connection, get the result
            return id;
        }
    }
    class ValidationTask implements Callable<Integer>{
        Integer id = 0;
        public ValidationTask(Integer val){
            this.id = val;
        }
        public Integer call(){
            // Add your verification result ehre
            if ( id > 0 ) {
                return id;
            }else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```